# Can the DXA 1.3 JAVA example webapp run with DXA 1.2 CM?

Tags: dxa, dxa-java

I am using DXA 1.2.1 JAVA. I want to try to upgrade my web application to DXA 1.3 first, then update the CM side later. Does the DXA 1.3 JAVA example webapp happen to be compatible with the items published by DXA 1.2?

Comment: Tried same in the past , did not encounter any issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that a DXA 1.3 web app will be compatible with DXA 1.2 CM, yes.